# How do you write a block diagonal matrix in components?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

I'm doing some calculations with diagonal block matrices and I'd like to write the components of the block matrix explicitly with respect to the blocks. For diagonal matrices this is easy using the Kronecker delta. For instance, given the matrix:

$ A = \left(\begin{matrix} a_1 &0&0\\ 0&a_2&0\\ 0&0&a_3 \end{matrix}\right)$

the corresponding components are (no summation over repeated indices):

$ A_{ij} = a_i\delta_{ij} $

Is there a similar way to write the components of a general block diagonal matrix? What I mean by "similar" is that the expression should use the components of the blocks and Kronecker deltas. I'd refer to the components of the blocks as $A_{ij}^{(k)}$, where $k=1,\ldots,n$, $i,j=1,\ldots m_k$, with $n$ the number of blocks and $m_k$ (squared) the dimension of the $k$-th block.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want a *single* expression which every component of the block diagonal matrix satisfies?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise it would be pretty easy to just define them "piecewise" (using braces, I don't know if it has a more specific name than this), with the conditions on the values of the indices being explicit (e.g. "$A_{ij} = A_{ij}^{(k)}$ for $i,j\in\{m_{k-1}+1,\ldots,m_{k-1}+m_k \}$ and zero otherwise).